# focus in record interactive grid oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, grid, oracle-apex, interactive

I have a grid where I do data manipulation using a sql pl, when I update the registry I use the command

```js
var model = apex.region("event")
    .widget()
    .interactiveGrid("getViews")
    .grid
    .model;

model.fetchRecords(model.data);
```

so that the focus remains on the record, however when inserting the record I did not find a way for the focus to fall on the released record, can you help me?

Comment: perhaps a little mode code, with a little more detail would make this a more clear question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can focus the particular cell that you have changed because more than one records can be modified simultaneously and saved.

By default the last modified row will be focused by IG.

If the select all check box is checked and more than or row is modified all the rows will be selected.

If you want to focus the last modified row even if the select all checkbox is checked then please follow the below steps:

Dynamic Action: Save Interactive Grid, Selection Type: Column(s), Region: Your IG Region, Columns: Select the columns for for which the focus of the row must happen when IG is saved

True Action: Javascript code

```
$( ".selector" ).grid( "GRID_STATIC_ID" );
```

If you want to the last selected row to be selected even after page submit then please follow the below steps:

Dynamic action: On Selection Change IG
, True action: Javascript Code

```
var gridID = "GRID_STATIC_ID";
var ig$ = apex.region(gridID).widget();
var grid = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");
var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectedRecords();
console.log(selectedRecord);
localStorage.setItem('lastSelectedRecord', JSON.stringify(selectedRecord));
```

Dynamic action: Page Load
, True action: Javascript Code

```
var gridID = "GRID_STATIC_ID";
var ig$ = apex.region(gridID).widget();
var grid = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");
grid.setSelectedRecords(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastSelectedRecord')));
```